# Is there evidence that tongue twisters help with listening and pronunciation?

Tags: reference-request, pronunciation, listening

The motivation for this question is a Chinese.SE answer:

> Have you tried practicing with tongue twisters (绕口令)? ... They can help with both listening and pronunciation. Repetition is really the only way to go if you want to master pronunciation.
>   <sub>[Krazer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/13/8099), 2011</sub>

I'm skeptical, and the author didn't give a reliable reference.

**Question**: Is there evidence that tongue twisters help with listening and pronunciation?

I'm looking for something academic here, not "some random person on the Internet said so".

The closest I found is Kember, Croot, and Patrick, *Phonological Encoding in Mandarin Chinese: Evidence from Tongue Twisters*, Language and Speech, 2014 ([DOI](https://doi.org/10.1177%2F0023830914562654)).  But it's not about improving one's language skills.